# Terragrunt - get specific folder name

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I have a file structure like this:

/git/projects/terragrunt-project/dev/vnet/terragrunt.hcl

I know that basename(dirname(get_terragrunt_dir())) will give me vnet

How can I pull out dev using a built in fuction?

Answer (score 1):

To get vnet is `basename(get_terragrunt_dir())`. Here: https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/1378 .
How to pull `dev`, after synching with a colleague, it is actually `basename(dirname(get_terragrunt_dir()))` ; somehow you provided the solution yourself.